# MVP - register click listener or use CDI events?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, vaadin, cdi

I'm evaluating if **CDI Events** could make sense for my new application. So far I always worked with `MVP` architectures where the `View` only has the UI elements and exposes them in public getters, whereas the `Presenter` registers click listeners on them.

I came around `CDI Events` and thought about to fire the click events in the `View` classes directly, and simply only `observe` these events in my `Presenters`.

Could you tell me which approach is the better one? Or why would you in general chose one over the other approach?

*MVP*:

```
class LoginView {   
    private Button loginButton;

    public void getButton() {
        return loginButton;
    }
}


class LoginPresenter {
    @Inject
    private LoginView view;

    public LoginPresenter() {
        view.getButton.addClickListener(new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
                //perform the login business logic
            }
        });
    }
}
```

*CDI Events*:

```
class LoginView {   
    private Button loginButton;

    @Inject
    private Events<LoginEvent> events;

    public LoginView() {
        loginButton.addClickListener(new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
                events.fire(new LoginEvent("login"));
            }
        });
    }
}


class LoginPresenter {
    private void listenLogin(@Observes LoginEvent evt) {
        //perform the login business logic
    }
}

class LoginEvent extends EventObject {
    public LoginEvent(String source) {
        super();
    }
}
```

(this example uses Vaadin, but framework choice should not matter for my question in general)

To me the main difference is: CDI requires no getters for the UI and no view member variables in the Presenter. On the downside, I need to create an extra event class for every event that is to be fired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, an event object would be one way.  Another would simply be to use a qualifier with the string value of what you want to observe.

```
@Inject
@Presenter("loginView")
private Event<Object> viewEvent;

public void onLoginView(@Observes @Presenter("loginView") Object viewEvent) {
    ... whatever has to happen
}
```

Would that work equivalently for you?

Otherwise, it's a pretty nice pattern.  Nice way to keep your application decoupled.

Comment: It turned out to be exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I don't use CDI events for sending events from a view to its presenter. The presenter and view have direct references to each other, which means that the CDI events would only cause extra overhead (both in code and performance) than when doing direct method calls. CDI events are useful when you want to decouple your code, for example, they are great for cross-view communication.

As a side note, I tend to keep all my com.vaadin imports away from the presenter, which would in your case mean that the view would implement the ClickListener and the presenter would have a method such as loginButtonClicked() - the view would call that method when the ClickEvent occurs. This way I could change the implementation of the view without affecting the presenter. It's probably a matter of taste if you think this is a good or bad practice. Typically, the defence for this approach is that keeping the presenter clean of view implementation specific technologies allows us to re-use the presenter even when implementing the view with another technology, but I think that is quite academic. The benefit I get is that I don't need to mock Vaadin components when doing unit tests for my presenter.

Comment: This is a very interesting approach! So far I always tried to keep a presenter reference out of the view, as in general it is said the view should only know about the UI, and not about the model or view. But what you wrote, especially with respect to UI implementation, makes much sense!

Comment: In some cases, you don't want the presenter to have a direct reference to the view implementation (for example, if you have multiple different implementation for the same view, such as desktop and mobile implementation), then you should abstract the view reference in the presenter behind an interface.

Comment: What about cases where you have to modify components in the view (eg enable/disable a button based on user input in a form). Would you do the user input validation and disabling in the view itself then? Because: if you perform these actions from the presenter, you'd have a circular dependency: the view has a reference to the presenter to call his methods on button click; and the presenter has reference to the view to access the button component.

Comment: Would you say the model you described is the Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM)?